# Посимвольный вывод в консоль

Tags: c++, консоль

Требуется **посимвольно** выводить строку в консоль.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>


int main() {
    std::string a = "Hello";
    for (int k = 0; k != a.size(); ++k) {
        std::cout << a[k];
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

Такое решение не работает: оно выводит после задержки сразу всю строку. Требуется же, чтобы буквы выводились каждая с задержкой.
Я так подозреваю, что проблема возникает из-за какого-то особенного механизма вывода в консоль?

Comment: Замените `std::cout` на `std::cerr`

Comment: Отключите буферизацию вывода или делайте `std::cout << a[k] << std::flush;`